# How to Update Item Quantity in Cart Tab

Tags: android

I am making a Ordered System, in which i am providing **Two Tabs** to user,

*First Tab* to select Item(s) and then add to cart.

*Second Tab* to view added Item(s) by user to purchase

**Problem:**

Whenever user will go back to Menu Tab to Update Quantity of an item already exist in cart, not able to show updated quantity like:

*Old Quantity*: 2

*New Quantity*: 4

In my *Cart Tab* i am always *getting 2 [old qty] in place of quantity*, but the nice thing for me i am *getting changes in Total Amount whenever i do change in Item Quantity*.

Please tell me where i am missing and where i am doing silly mistake...

*ViewCartActivity.Java:*

```
   @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume();
        if (Constants.mItem_Detail.size() == 0) 
        {
            return;
        }

        Double mGTotal = Double.parseDouble(Constants.mItem_Detail.get(0).get(SingleProductActivity.KEY_TOTAL));
        for (int i = 1; i < Constants.mItem_Detail.size(); i++) 
        {   
        mGTotal = mGTotal + Double.parseDouble(Constants.mItem_Detail.get(i).get(SingleProductActivity.KEY_TOTAL));
        }
        mGrandTotal = String.valueOf(mGTotal);
        mTxtViewGrandTotal.setText(mGrandTotal);
        myTextVeiwGrandTotal.setText(mGrandTotal);
        mTotal = String.valueOf(Constants.mItem_Detail.size());
        mItems.setText(mTotal);

}
```

*Tab.Java:*

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    Constants.mItem_Detail.clear();

}
```

Comment: Debug your program with break point, defnitily your problem will solve..